# Coaxial 75ohm cable parallel to electrical mains 127V AC @ 60Hz

Tags: signal, mains, interference, coaxial

Everywhere we look at, the same recommendation is made: "never run coaxial cable parallel to electrical cables". Well, I get it, but.... **I have no other option™**. More than that, those cables have to run inside the very same conduit (about 1" thick) for less than 1m.

Well... the same guidance is given about ethernet cables. And I never had problem with CAT-5 cable alongside electrical power for about 1 meter length (maybe that ethernet section cannot reach 1Gbps speeds, but I don't need that either).

My question is about quantification of this "never run [...]". That is:

**How much signal degradation (or any other harmful interference) should I expect in a coaxial cable 75ohm in parallel to 127V AC @ 60Hz for some given length?**

An approximation is more than enough. How does it compare to other common sources of interference, say, CMB or airports nearby?

If current is relevant, consider that these electrical wires power a medium LCD TV set (like 120W in use, or 2W in standby).

If the nature of signal is relevant, the coaxial cable transmits 50mbps full duplex from the operator router ca. 100m away.

Comment: Not an answer, but you may benefit by adding ferrite sleeves around the power lines just before the power and data lines become close and parallel, and also again just after they separate.

Comment: How well-shielded is the coax? If it has a particularly good shield, it would have less interference than if you had a particularly poor shield.

Comment: What receive circuit are you envisaging and, is there any modulation going on in the transmit signal? A single line-end-interface cannot transmit full-duplex (it's a paradox or contradiction).

Comment: @Andyaka I'm not an engineer, I can't really answer your question. My ISP has it all set up for me: a coaxial cable out of my wall, connected to a router that decodes it to some ethernet ports and wifi antenna. Perhaps I should have not said "full duplex". If it is not possible, then maybe the wire protocol arranges for some time slicing for either side to transmit to the other side in turn, not in tandem. What I want to say was that this line receives 50Mbps downlink and 50Mbps (maybe less) uplink. Just to give you an idea of the nature of the signals carried.

Comment: The elephant in the room:  Mixing signaling cables and power cables in the same conduit may be severely frowned-upon by your local electrical codes.  The requirement to keep them separate is there in order to minimize the possibility of your current-limited circuits becoming suddenly non-current limited (due to a short/insulation failure), and then pose a fire risk.  Check your regs.

Comment: I guess that “signal degradation” will be more severe if the AC current has a HF noise (as an El Cheapo Power supply - from unknown brand at 1$ stores). The larger the HF current, and longer path, the noisier pickup. Using ferrite toroids at each extremity of merged AC+Ethernet could avoid major problems. How to measure and compare something sporadic as Power-On + Data transfer = assume to reach a critical threshold? I believe nobody  has such answer.  A **final point**: check for perfect insulation and visual integrity for all wire legs, to avoid galvanic AC paths= catastrophic for Ethernet.

Comment: running cables parallel is bad juju as nasty current spikes can be easily coupled into your coax.  You're making a transformer, albeit a rather poor one.  In your application, it might not be an issue. If you do have problems, don't be surprised!

Comment: @ChrisKnudsen thanks for bringing this point up. Though I don't personally expect any short circuit for such a small span of conduit, with brand new cables, it is definitely something we must pay attention to. Perhaps the whole "never run signalling cable parallel to electrical cables" thing conceals exactly this concern. I never thought of this. I'll try my best to avoid this worst case scenario (aka visual careful inspection), bc I don't want to burn my devices and don't want my home on fire.

Comment: @EJE you mean a cheap power supply elsewhere in the same AC circuit? I don't expect the power supply inside the TV set to be that cheap. Does "galvanic AC path" mean a short-circuit for non-experts/non-engineers?

Comment: @Kartman the whole point of my question is to assess this "running cables parallel is bad". At first I thought only about HF interference (aka noise) so high that could severely disrupt internet service. But it has been brought to my attention the potential of short-circuit hazard, which is definitely a point. And I'm indebted to the many people that took their time to give me hints/info about what to look after (the ferrite sleeve for instance).

Comment: @rslemos PS from TV should be well designed. This is not my concern. Sometimes you have a videogame close to the TV, with a Charger of Cordless joysticks: *That* may be noise-dirty. Sometimes a guy uses a 12V PS to light-up an LED strip: another noise-source, eventually connect to the same side of the TV rack.

Comment: @rslemos and about the ‘galvanic’ I said: it is more like some partial loss of insulation, when for instance Two plastic insulation are damaged at different positions, so they do Not Touch directly, but condensation, or ‘dust do dirty’ being hygroscopic, would create a low power path that could disturb telephone landlines (I had this issue in the past) and even our digital ‘low voltage’ lines. So, it is less than a “classic short circuit”, but is conductive enough to give anyone nightmares to troubleshoot: that telephone line ‘partially’ connected to ground (no AC) on some rainy days.

Answer (score 2):

It's probably fine. Digital signals aren't terribly sensitive to interference. Combined foil/braid shielded cable (RG6) would be better than just braid (RG59). Ferrite sleeves, as suggested by Math Keeps Me Busy may also help, but I wouldn't bother unless I saw a problem.

Comment: As I understand, ferrite sleeves around mains would only protect the TV set (or maybe other appliances upstream) from harmful HF interference. Or not?

Comment: @rslemos In most cases, interference is "reciprocal". Blocking interference from device A to B equally blocks interference from device B to A.

Comment: @rslemos  Electrical devices connected to mains power can introduce electrical noise on the mains line. That noise could then get coupled to your data lines. The ferrite sleeves will help keep the noise level on your mains line down, which in turn may lessen the noise coupled to your data lines.

Answer (score 1):

As long as the shielding is good there should be any strong disturbance. Please note that shielding requires more than buying a good shielded coax cable. It is also about properly connecting the shield on both ends to the GND planes (and chassis if chassis is connected to GND). You can use either 360° bond or cable clamp but never use the pigtail for instance. About ferrite beads across the power line, that will avoid common mode current at high frequencies to flow through the power line down to the AC/DC SMPS. You can place one that will enclose both AC power cables.

Comment: All connections to be done with BNC connectors. Does it qualify as 360º bond?

Comment: BNC connector shoud be OK since the shield is connected to ground. But it does not really qualify as 360° bond since 360° bond is realized just before entering the chassis, using a metal ring screwed on the chassis. But connection with BNC cable to a PCB should also work fine.